# Slowness trying to send many telemetries using TelemetryClient

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I'm using the ApplicationInsights NuGet in C#:

My use case is a bit different, since our system is performance sensitive, we log telemetries in a file and then want to upload it to application insights.

Our code may generate 100Ks or even millions of telemetries, we then have a code that goes over the files and uploads them to application insights using the TelemetryClient in C#.

We noticed it takes ~10m to upload 300K of records, which is way more than what we expected.

1. We tried increasing the buffer size like this without success (was still 10m):

   ```
        var configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        configuration.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        var channel = new InMemoryChannel
        {
            MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity = 10000
        };
        configuration.TelemetryChannel = channel;

        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

        _telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = sessionId ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   ```
2. We tried creating 10 different TelemetryClient instances, splitting the telemetries into batches and uploading, still - 10m.

We went over the code, we can see that it buffers the telemetries and then sends them in batches to the azure service, but we couldn't figure out why it is taking so much time.

Would appreciate if someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Gilad, how did you measure that the upload took 10 minutes per 300K records?

Answer (score 0):

> why it is taking so much time?

If you want to send the telemetry data into Application Insights, it has **latency of under [5 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#how-long-does-it-take-for-telemetry-to-be-collected-)**. If we were ***sending large no of data files into Application Insights, it takes more than 5 mins as per data available in the files***.

The Process behind while sending telemetry data into Application Insights is because of **aggregation**, the **telemetry client send data into buffer, and it send into batches**. Throughout the process it adds your telemetry data into Application takes time to show in Azure portal.

The aggregation contains some background process of

- Ingesting
- Processing
- Indexing
- Storing your telemetry data into Application Insights.

#### How to Quickly get telemetry response in Application Insights

1. Try to enable the **Developer Mode** has **true** in your application so that we can see our telemetry data in application insights with minimal ***latency of under 2 mins***.

   (***But using this Developer Mode= true It cannot do the aggregation process it just push our messages into Application Insights***)

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
```

2. Use the **[Live stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream)** to get the telemetry data ***within a sec*** in your azure portal.

Comment: Wow thanks, i'll give it a try and share the results. My concern BTW is less about how much time it takes for the data to show in the portal and more about how much time it takes for the process to send the requests. Your advises sound promising :-)

Comment: Yes, make a try. It will take 1 or 2 mins if we keep Developer mode has true. In live stream it takes few secs to shows the telemetry