# how much delay if we remove DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule from app insight setting?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I just read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config) from microsoft:
[image]
So I should remove this from production environment. However, on production environment, we setup some alerts to inform us when a burst of exception happens in my site.

Does anyone know much delay we are talking about here? If it is less than 1 or 2 minutes, it is ok. But if the delay is around 10 or 15 minutes, I don't think our production site can wait that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know much delay we are talking about here?

Normally, it takes around **under 5 mins** to send telemetry data into application Insights.

> If it is less than 1 or 2 minutes, it is ok. But if the delay is around 10 or 15 minutes, I don't think our production site can wait that long.

If you are sending large no of data to Applicaiton Insights it takes as per the data available(Extend more than 5 mins).

If you are using **Developer Mode** has **true** you can minimize the latency under 2 mins.

###### Note: But it was not recommended for production Environment.

Refer one of my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73287162/15997690) for detailed information.

Comment: hi, for this setting, is it by default off for .net core/5/6 (as we need to set it manually in json or code) and by default on for .net framework (as we just used the config file generated and didn't change anything)?

Comment: yes, as per the requirement you can change